# Do we have a solution if oxygen runs out

Tags: biology, technology, atmosphere, oxygen

I'm not a scientist but I know at the moment we don't have a huge amount of Oxygen in our atmosphere but what would happened if the Ozone layer was broken and all the oxygen escaped how could we overcome the problem of oxygen deprivation? Is there a solution for this already in place and if so, what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The ozone layer does not keep oxygen from escaping into space.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean hydrogen? There are concerns about losing unbound hydrogen to space and we have a very limited supply. Oxygen makes up 1/5th of the atmosphere and it's heavy enough to be trapped by earth's gravity. Besides, the ozone layer IS oxygen

Comment: Is this worldbuilding, or just another reason to worry about the future from your point of view? Fortunately, it's not going to happen on this planet quite the way you indicate.

Answer (score 6):

I would challenge your assumptions that

> we don't have a huge amount of Oxygen in our atmosphere

It has taken us 200+ years of industrial revolution and CO2 emission to make a dent in the [atmospheric concentration of CO2](https://www.climate.gov/news-features/understanding-climate/climate-change-atmospheric-carbon-dioxide) and bring it from 280 ppm to 420 ppm

[image]

Oxygen is about 20% of our atmosphere, and even if all sources would stop now, it would take a while to make the atmosphere unbreathable for us. (1 ppm = 0.0001%)

But, yes, if there would be no more photosynthetic organisms dumping oxygen in the atmosphere, aerobic life would be doomed, since we have no alternative in place.

This is precisely a possible scenario for life on Earth once the main photosynthetic path will stop.

Also your other assumption that

> if the Ozone layer was broken and all the oxygen escaped

is wrong. Earth gravity well is deep enough that it can trap oxygen at the current temperature, so no appreciable loss can happen, ozone layer or not. Ozone is useful at filtering UV light, not at trapping gases inside the atmosphere.

[image]

If Earth could be stripped of oxygen by something other than self consumption, we would have worse things to worry about than anoxia.